# Where is a good place to look for debugging a problem in TestFlight for an ionic react app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, testflight, capacitor

I use react, ionic, and firebase primarily for the app i have published in test flight.

When i am testing it on a simulator, a real device, and even the web browser locally, it all runs as expected. However, when I successfully published it to TestFlight and the app opens, it does not allow me to leave the first page (the login page).

I can click the buttons and the functions will trigger, however, firebase shows no sign of being reached when I look at the logs and I cannot navigate to any other page either (the sign up page or otherwise).

this is my capacitor.config.ts file:

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from "@capacitor/cli";

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: "com.traineraid",
  appName: "Traineraid",
  webDir: "build",
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
};
export default config;
```

I don't have any idea where else the problems might lie, so if any advice at all for where to look would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [safari technology preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) to debug and it should point you in the right direction.